# Problem setting up rails-perftest gem - HomepageTest#run _must_ return a Result (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, rubygems, performance-testing

I am working on installing the rails-perftest gem in my rails application. Reference link:
https://github.com/rails/rails-perftest
When I run the bundle exec rake test:benchmark command.

The first error  I got was File does not exist: test_helper which I solved by creating a new rails application and using the test_helper.rb that was generated in my current rails application.

Now, I am getting have a new error when I  run the bundle exec rake test:benchmark command.

```
/home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:961:in `run_one_method': HomepageTest#run _must_ return a Result (RuntimeError)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1)
/home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/home/redd/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:benchmark
```

`Rails version 5.1.4`
`Ruby version 2.5.1`

I would appreciate help on setting up the rails-perftest gem in my application. Thank you for your time.